# Latest Security update "firmware for linux kernel drivers" failed - how do i fix this?

Tags: linux, drivers, ubuntu-12.04, linux-kernel, firmware

I have copied the update-manager's update failure/error message

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ...
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 459112 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace linux-firmware 1.79.1 (using .../linux-firmware_1.79.4_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-firmware ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: data error'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.4_all.deb
Error in function:

The OS is trying to upgrade to "Version 1.79.4: 

* Add rt2x00 firmware file rt3290.bin " and is currently at version 1.79.1
```

The dialog box says

> Package operation failed,The installation or removal of a package failed".

How does one fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough disk space to do the upgrade?

Comment: Yes @KevinVW I am sure there is enough disk space to do the upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing to unpack the .deb file it downloaded:

```
Unpacking replacement linux-firmware ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: data error'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.4_all.deb (--unpack):
subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
```

which suggests that the file is corrupted. You can try removing it and forcing it to be redownloaded:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.4_all.deb
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install all pending updates with

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

(note: I believe all the blurb at the top about Perl before 'Reading Database...' is a completely separate error).

Comment: Thanks for that. It worked. Takeaways for me - Read the logs more carefully next time.